# Selecting entries according to running total

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to select from a list of files only so many files that their total size does not exceed a threshold (i.e. the amount of free space on the target drive).

I understand that I could do this by adding up file sizes in a loop until I hit the threshold and then use that number to select files from the list. However, is it possible to do that with a LINQ-query instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that by using a closure:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp");
var files = directory .GetFiles();

long maxTotalSize = 2000000;

long aggregatedSize = 0;
var result = files.TakeWhile(fileInfo => 
{
    aggregatedSize += fileInfo.Length;
    return aggregatedSize <= maxTotalSize;
});
```

Theres a caveat though, because the variable `aggregatedSize` may get modified after you have left the scope where it has been defined.

You could wrap that in an extension method though - that would eliminate the closure:

```
public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetWithMaxAggregatedSize(this IEnumerable<FileInfo> files, long maxTotalSize)
{
    long aggregatedSize = 0;
    return files.TakeWhile(fileInfo => 
    {
        aggregatedSize += fileInfo.Length;
        return aggregatedSize <= maxTotalSize;
    });
}
```

You finally use the method like this:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp");
var files = directory.GetFiles().GetWithMaxAggregatedSize(2000000);
```

**EDIT:** I replaced the `Where`-method with the `TakeWhile`-method. The `TakeWhile`-extension will stop once the threshold has been reached, while the `Where`-extension will continue. Credits for bringing up the `TakeWhile`-extension go to Tim Schmelter.

Answer (score 8):

This could work (`files` is a `List<FileInfo>`):

```
var availableSpace = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
    .First(d => d.Name == @"C:\").AvailableFreeSpace;
long usedSpace = 0;
var availableFiles = files
    .TakeWhile(f => (usedSpace += f.Length) < availableSpace);
foreach (FileInfo file in availableFiles)
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
}
```

Comment: I didn't think of `TakeWhile` when writing my answer, that's a nice one! But mind the modified closure in this answer, too. You can circumvent that by wrapping the code in an extension method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. After the edit, I believe that @Spontifixus' answer is the more complete one.